# Parallel lines on an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I have an earth modeled as an ellipsoid. I have some line geometries at many places on this model. I have the x,y,z values of all the points on these lines/curve segments. My question is, is there any approach to find coordinates of a parallel curve on this ellipsoid?

Comment: How are you defining parallel?

Comment: @N.Owad More like something that visually looks parallel. The latitudes and longitudes for example. I know they are not perfectly parallel, but they do seem parallel. But my curve may not exactly lie along a latitude, it might span across latitudes at 45 degrees for example.

Comment: The longitude lines (meridians) aren’t “parallel”, since they get closer as you go towards the poles.

Answer (score 2):

If your lines were actually geodesics on a sphere, then all their points would lie in a single plane, and a second plane parallel to that would intersect the sphere in a curve which has constant distance to the original geodesic, but which is not itself a geodesic. For “visually looks parallel”, the distinction between sphere and ellipsoid might be negligible.